# Disable password reset from Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

How I can disable password reset? I need prevent resetting passwords on login page. How I can do it?

I tried do:

```
Auth::routes(['register' => false, 'password.request' => false, 'password.reset' => false]);
```

But not working. Password reset is working.

Answer (score 15):

Change,

```
'password.reset' => false
```

To,

```
'reset' => false
```

---

If that doesn't work, in `ForgotPasswordController`, you will see that a trait `SendsPasswordResetEmails` is used, in that you will find the function `showLinkRequestForm` which you can override:

```
public function showLinkRequestForm()
{
    return view('auth.passwords.email');
}
```

and replace it with a redirect to go back, or a 404, or something else that you want.

---

Alternatively, you could override the routes.

Comment: Worked for me laravel-9. Great job

Answer (score 4):

Inside of :

```
Auth::routes();
```

You can use :

```
    // Authentication Routes...
Route::get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
Route::post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

// Registration Routes...
Route::get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
Route::post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');

// Password Reset Routes...
Route::get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.request');
Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email');
Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset');
Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset')->name('password.update');
```

And delete which you don't want.

Answer (score 1):

Because I can not add a comment yet, I'd like to add to Omid Reza Heidari's comment. Using

```
Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
```

without `->name('password.update')` will results in error "Route [password.update] not defined" when using the default view. The last route should thus be

```
Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset')->name('password.update');
```